# get project name out of ILaunchConfiguration object

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to get the executed project name out of an ILaunchConfiguration object, but I am struggling to find an easy way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the proper code for this:

```
String projectName = configuration.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR", "");
```

where `Cconfiguration` is an object of the type `ILaunchConfiguration` which I am using in the method `public void launch(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, String mode,
            ILaunch launch, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException`

Answer (score 2):

An `ILaunchConfiguration` can describe many different types of launch some of which don't have any associated project (an Eclipse application launch for example).

For a Java program launch you can try:

```
String projectName = launchConfiguration.getAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_PROJECT_NAME, (String)null);
```

Update:

IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants is `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants` in the `org.eclipse.jdt.launching` plugin. The constant is `"org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR"`.

Comment: Thanks! but I couldn't find the right import class for `IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants` so I have used my own answer.

Comment: Added the import information, but just using the constant is OK.